# AWS Opsworks executing deploy hooks in "setup" stage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am setting up a rails 4 app on AWS opsworks.

When I boot up an instance, I see that the [deploy hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-hooks.html) are running in the "setup" lifecycle event of opsworks rather than the deploy event.

I am facing problems in running asset precompile because of this. I cannot get expected behaviour because these callbacks happen in the setup lifecycle. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. When first booting up an instance, Opsworks will run events in this order - Setup, Deploy, Configure.

[More info](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-events.html)